How to extrapolate/forcast data with a linear mixed model
I built a linear mixed model with data from a cohort of patients followed from 3 years before the start of the treatment to 24months after. The variable of interest in their blood pressure.
I would like to use my model to forecast predicted blood pressure value after the 24months follow up.
If anyone knows how to proceed that would be amazing ?
PS : I am working on R

Proceed very carefully and be sure to not trust your forecasts too much, until they have been shown to work.

thank you very much for your input Peter ! I will. This is just an exploratory analysis to add element to the discussion but the main results will be the one from observed data. I'll be sure to take every precaution needed when discussing it since it is indeed an extrapolation and nowhere comparable to real life data.
Would you have any idea of how to proceed by any chance ?
Thank you again for your time !

Not familiar with R sufficiently, but you could start by writing the mathematical form of your model, and the implied probability distribution for the dependent variable. From then on it should be easy
